# Hibernate and library sql cp30 in java swing

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

I use java swing NetBean to work with the hibernate and library sql cp30.I've seen a few similar questions but I can not fix your problems. Please help me

```
public class Main{

    final static SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        List list = sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MdGmail.class).list();
    }
}
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/steadfast?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">400</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <mapping resource="DaTaTable/MdDataweb.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="DaTaTable/MdBlogger.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="DaTaTable/MdParseBlogger.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="DaTaTable/MdGmail.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="DaTaTable/MdParse.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="DaTaTable/MdPageFormat.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I receive the following message after running

```
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: DaTaTable/MdDataweb.hbm.xml
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:06 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: DaTaTable/MdBlogger.hbm.xml
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:07 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: DaTaTable/MdParseBlogger.hbm.xml
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:07 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: DaTaTable/MdGmail.hbm.xml
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:07 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: DaTaTable/MdParse.hbm.xml
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:07 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: DaTaTable/MdPageFormat.hbm.xml
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:07 CH org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:07 CH org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/steadfast?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:07 CH org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:07 CH org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
4 [MLog-Init-Reporter] INFO com.mchange.v2.log.MLog - MLog clients using slf4j logging.
556 [main] INFO com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry - Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.1 [built 16-June-2015 00:06:36 -0700; debug? true; trace: 10]
758 [main] INFO com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@6146268e [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@50734ff0 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, identityToken -> 1hge14a9dmupdvd1okhipx|17dc5cf, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 1, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 400, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 1, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@98b7961 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge14a9dmupdvd1okhipx|1b7ecdb, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/steadfast?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull, properties -> {user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge14a9dmupdvd1okhipx|d86395, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:08 CH org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:08 CH org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
thg 11 29, 2015 3:30:08 CH org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no errors in your logs. Its picking up the default `hibernate.cfg.xml` file from your classpath.

Try to print something to the console and it will be successful.

or you can use `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` class instead of `AnnotationConfiguration` as it is deprecated.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thank Moataz Mohammad and localhost999 helped me very much,@localhost999 your code I had applied it and was great success it's amazing.

Comment: I hope you help me more problems to create a function declaration with hibernate in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011954/java-hibernate-declared-connection-effective

Answer (score 1):

AnnotationConfiguration is already deprecated and you don't use annotations actually, so I recommend org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.