# Java hibernate declared connection effective

Tags: java, hibernate

This is the command to display information data sheet, I see the declaration it is repeated

**CODE 1**

```
public class DBTable {

    public List<MdGmail> showGmail() {
       Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
       SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory();
       currentSession = sf.getCurrentSession();
       currentSession.beginTransaction();
       return currentSession.createCriteria(MdGmail.class).list();
    }

    public List<MdBlogger> showBlogger() {
       Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
       SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory();
       currentSession = sf.getCurrentSession();
       currentSession.beginTransaction();    
       return currentSession.createCriteria(MdBlogger.class).list();
    }
}
```

In my class DBTable,I create a list function to display data table in a database as table gmail,order...
With the first code 1 need to rewrite the declaration for each function, so what I want is to create a connection function for all with code 2

But with the way this declaration it will not update the value was changed in the database

**CODE 2**

```
public class DBTable {

    private static final Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    private static final SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory();
    private static Session currentSession;

    public DBTable() {
        currentSession = sf.getCurrentSession();
        currentSession.beginTransaction();
    }

    private static DBTable instance = null;

    public static DBTable getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBTable();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public List<MdGmail> showTableGmail() {
        return currentSession.createCriteria(MdGmail.class).list();
    }
    public List<MdGmail> showTableOrder() {
        return currentSession.createCriteria(MdGmail.class).list();
    }
}
```

And if use new additional data function, the connection will be closed and command data showing that my table would stop working.Please help me

```
    public boolean saveOrUpdateGmail(MdGmail table) {
    try {
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(table);
        currentSession.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        currentSession.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand your question,anyway have you tried with sf.openSession()?

Comment: If the issue is not resolved yet, edit the question with the error messages in your logs.

Comment: Thank @localhost999 My statement is wrong about logical so it not errors.Because I call the following statement Table.getInstance DB (). ShowGmail () I tried several times I finally overcome by simple, I erase command check "instance null "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest strategy of using Hibernate is open a session (or get current one), begin a transaction, do request, commit, and close a session for every operation (`showTableGmail, saveOrUpdateGmail`). So you need to delete all code from `DBTable()` constructor and do something like [this](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/factory/HibernateSessionFactory.java#L41).

Comment: Currently I do not understand about it, but I will consider it carefully for your program.Thanks for your suggestions